# Error When Uploading File: @using Html.BeginForm

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, methods

I received error saying:

> HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
> dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
> temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
> sure that it is spelled correctly. Requested URL:
> /PCController/Progress

PCController is my controller's name.
This is from my controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Progress()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Progress(HttpPostedFile file)
    {
        try
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string _FileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                string _path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/PC"), _FileName);
                file.SaveAs(_path);
            }
            ViewBag.Message = "File Uploaded Successfully!!";
            return View();
        }
        catch
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "File upload failed!!";
            return View();
        }
    }
```

And this one is for my View:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Progress", "PCController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                        {
                            <div>
                                @Html.TextBox("file", "", new { type = "file" }) <br />

                                <input type="submit" value="Upload" />

                                @ViewBag.Message

                            </div>


                        }
```

Comment: whey this "/PCController/Progress" I guss Controller should not be there so it should be like "/PC/Progress". Put your routes.config and class name also.

Comment: Many thanks! I shouldnt put Controller there, should be "PC" instead.

Answer (score 1):

I shouldnt put Controller there, should be "PC" instead.

@using (Html.BeginForm("Progress", "PC", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

@Html.TextBox("file", "", new { type = "file" })

```
                            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />

                            @ViewBag.Message

                        </div>


                    }
```